# onCreateOptionsMenu called after onResume on JB 4.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have the following fragment in my application:

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  private MenuItem refresh = null;

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //.....

    // NPE here
    refresh.setActionView(R.layout.indeterminate_progress_action);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh_menu, menu);
    refresh = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_refresh);
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    refresh.setActionView(null);
  }
}
```

Basically when the user starts the Activity I want to display a progress spinner, in the actionbar, until the loader completes. Prior to Android 4.2 everything worked fine. On Android 4.2 I get the following error:

```
11-24 13:37:14.811: E/AndroidRuntime(17850): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 13:37:14.811: E/AndroidRuntime(17850):    at com.MyApp.library.fragments.MyFragment.onActivityCreated(TabFragment.java:65)
```

After adding some break point I realized onCreateOptionsMenu was getting called after onActivityCreated.  Is there another life cycle event I can use?  Is there a better was to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Um, why not move your `setActionView()` call to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, then? And perhaps do it conditionally depending upon whether or not the load is done?

Comment: Kinda works. Seems like `onCreateOptionsMenu` gets called after `onLoadFinished` too.  Since I have tabs with multiple loaders `hasRunningLoaders` isn't useful in determining if load has finished.  Guess I will have to use a Boolean value to track the state.

Comment: Android issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39721

Comment: Can you post full error? What line of code is 65? Also can you not just check for != null before using the object, I have fixed similar problems in onCreateOptionsMenu before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11379474/1847899 maybe this is your problem .. ?

Comment: I have Same problem, onCreateOptionsMenu gets called after onResume on Marshmallow

Answer (score 4):

I've used `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in this way to achieve what you are trying to do. 
(not tested but should give you an idea.)

```
private boolean mIsLoading = true;

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    refresh = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_refresh);
    if (!mIsLoading) {
        refresh.setActionView(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    mIsLoading = false;
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: How come onPrepareOptionsMenu method return void; I think I just saw a pussy cat; scared my freaking mind