# menu inflating calls multiple times at fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-fragments, contextmenu, android-menu

I use Fragments and when I switch to nested Fragment, which implements `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` my menu inflates quantity of times when I get to that nested Fragment. How can I avoid this? I also implement constructor of Fragment with methods:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

When I tried to implement siple solution as:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     // TODO Add your menu entries here
   if(!isInflated)
         {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.contacts_archive_menu, menu);
         isInflated = true;
         }
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

 }
```

but my menu wasn't inflate after the screen rotation.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I solved it simply by clearing menu before ionflating of it:

```
     @Override
     public void   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
          menu.clear();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.call_menu, menu);
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

     }
```

Comment: what is this bug? any idea

Comment: Thanks for this. We have an array of fragment that inflate menu.

Answer (score 8):

Just check the count of `menu` items. Meaning `menu.size()==0` ,no `menu` items are present,then inflate with `layout menu`,else don't inflate at all.

```
 @Override
 public void   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      if (menu.size() == 0)
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.call_menu, menu);
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

 }
```

Comment: Great.. its best way instead of menu.clear() because in that case menu inflated all time.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the invalidateOptionsMenu, example:

```kotlin
private var isMenuCreated = false

...

override fun invalidateOptionsMenu() {
  Log.d("invalidateOptionsMenu")
  if (!isMenuCreated) {
    super.invalidateOptionsMenu()
  }
}

...

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
  ...
  isMenuCreated = true
  return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use before replace.

```
 fragment = new EditMyProfile();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionEditProfile =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
 fragmentTransactionEditProfile.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
 fragmentTransactionEditProfile.commit();
```